# cs50 pset 1 cash only prints out zeros

Tags: cs50

I tried figuring out what the problem was with my code, i checked if the brackets were ok, but i still cant figure it out.this is pset 1 cash

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
 {

 float dollars;
   int cents = 0;
   int coin_amount = 0;

do
    {
//prompt user for amount of change
    dollars = get_float("change: ");
    }
 while (cents < 0);
    
  cents = round(cents * 100);

    
     while (cents >= 25)
    {
        cents = cents - 25;
        coin_amount++;
    }
    while (cents >= 10)
    {
        cents = cents - 10;
        coin_amount++;
    }
    while (cents >= 5)
    {
        cents = cents - 5;
        coin_amount++;
    }
    while (cents >= 1)
    {
        cents = cents - 1;
        coin_amount++;
    }
  printf("%d\n",coin_amount);
}
```

Input: 1 dollar

Expected Output:4 coins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bug is that you say `cents = round(cents * 100)` when you really meant to say `cents = dollars * 100`

It is difficult to read the code because of the lack of consistent indenting, but your first do while loop also isn't working properly.  It checks the value of cents but you don't actually try to convert from dollars to cents until after you're out of the loop.  In other words, the do-while loop will only ever be run exactly once.  You could put a negative number into it and break the program's intent.  You need to convert to cents within that loop.  If this works, appreciate the upvote.